# Spriteの消える演出を作りたい

Tags: cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x 3.8を使っています。

Spriteのキャラクターを
上から下に見えなくなっていくように
演出を作りたいのですが、

Scaleではキャラクターが縮んでいく風になってしまい
なにかダサいです.....

runActionの中で何かいい手段などありますでしょうか？><

Answer (score 0):

Dorirumanさんのおっしゃることを実現しようとするとフレームごとにUV設定が必要になると思われますが私はcocos2dのActionの中にそういった機能を見つけることはできませんでした。

力技ですが、
１．SpriteFrameのRect設定で徐々に表示される範囲を狭めるようなAnimateを作成
２．スケールを小さくするActionを作成
この二つを同時に再生するSpawnを作ってrunActionするのはどうでしょう？
スケールがかかる原点を上端や下端に合わせたいのであれば事前にsetAnchorPointしておくとよいかもしれません。